# Simulate button clicks in a windows form using powershell.

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I have a basic windows form application written in C# in Visual Studio that has some buttons that open windows with more buttons. It doesnt do anything useful, I'm using it to try simulate a series of button presses using powershell.

I am trying to learn powershell, and I've been looking online to see how to use powershell to open the windows form exe and then click a button on the form, and then click another button in the window that pops up.

So far I can open the executable, but that was very straight forward.

I am thinking of  using the sendkeys method. Perhaps I could associate keyboard shortcuts with buttons and then have powershell type in those shortcuts.

Or when the exe opens, powershell hits tab a certain amount of times until the button is focused and then hits enter.

I'm sure there is an easier way to do this. Any guidance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please google for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this from PowerShell would be to change the button text in C# to include a shortcut key by using `&` in the text, for a button that says "Open Form" you could set the text to `Open &Form` which would make `Alt + F` click the button via the shortcut.

Source: [Creating Access Keys for Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983581(v=vs.71).aspx)

Then from from your PowerShell script all you have to do is use `SendKeys` to simulate `Alt + F` to click the button.

Modified example from TechNet:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("<NAME OF YOUR APPLICATION>")

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%F")
```

Source: [Windows Script Host SendKeys Method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008.aspx)